# How to convert numeric to character in R following specific constraints

Tags: r, string, printf

I am wondering if there is a way to convert a numeric vector in R to a character vector following these constraints:

- Maximum length: 7 characters
- Scientific notation: Only if necessary in the 7 character space
- Decimal point: ALWAYS present
- The exponent in scientific notation: Minimum number of digits (e.g.,
  use E-1 instead of E-01)

An example of how an output should look like is the following:

```
     1.
1.04167
-14.194
6.57E-4
0.69291
  3.348
 15203.
     0.
    1.3
2.0E-12
2.11E-5
```

I wrote the following but it is too long, the exponents still have two digits, and I am not entirely sure it will always work:

```
as_7digit_char <- as.character(numberVector)
as_7digit_char_scientifics_index <- nchar(as_7digit_char) > 7
as_7digit_char[nchar(as_7digit_char) > 7 ] <- sprintf("%#.2G", numberVector[nchar(as_7digit_char) > 7 ] )
as_7digit_char[!grepl(pattern = "E", x = as_7digit_char, fixed = T)  &as_7digit_char_scientifics_index] <- as.character(numberVector)[!grepl(pattern = "E", x = as_7digit_char, fixed = T)  &  as_7digit_char_scientifics_index]
as_7digit_char <- substr(as_7digit_char, start=1, stop=7)
as_7digit_char[!grepl(pattern = ".", x = as_7digit_char, fixed = T)] <- paste0(as_7digit_char[!grepl(pattern = ".", x = as_7digit_char, fixed = T)], ".")
as_7digit_char <- substr(as_7digit_char, start=1, stop=7)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use `sprintf`?

```
sprintf("%7.6e", x)
#[1] "1.000000e+00"  "1.041670e+00"  "-1.419400e+01" "6.570000e-04"
#[5] "6.929100e-01"  "3.348000e+00"  "1.520300e+04"  "0.000000e+00"
#[9] "1.300000e+00"  "2.000000e-12"  "2.110000e-05"
```

---

### Sample data

```
x <- c(     1.,
1.04167,
-14.194,
6.57E-4,
0.69291,
  3.348,
 15203.,
     0.,
    1.3,
2.0E-12,
2.11E-5)
```

Comment: Thanks but no, the output you show using sprintf does not meet the constraints I listed.

Comment: @nrj Ok no problem ; tbh your constraints don't make much sense to me. For example: *"Only if necessary in the 7 character space"* I don't understand this sentence; what does that mean? It would help if you would edit your question to include your expected output.

Comment: Yes, the constraints are odd, but that's what I need for a Fortran model.

What that constrain means is the following:

Let's say you have the number 123456, then no scientific notation is needed and the output should be "123456."

On the other hand, if you have 12345678, scientific notation is necessary to fit in a 7 character space, and the output should be "1.234E7"

Comment: @nrj I see, thanks for the clarification; I know Fortran quite well; I spent the beginning of my professional life coding in Fortran 77/90 a lot. I still can't think of a situation where Fortran would require numbers being formatted so oddly. Fortran's `FORMAT` syntax is actually quite similar to that of `sprintf`. I just wonder if this is more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have no control over the Fortran code, it is a big model developed by a University, and for some reason, they need the input in that format. I agree it is a terrible format, but I need it that way.